# How one can show $P(ax+n|x)=P(n)$?

Tags: probability, signal-processing, noise

Let $x$ be a signal and $n$ be an independent noise. How one can show $P(ax+n|x)=P(n)$?
Thanks.

Well, let $y=ax+n$, so we have $n=y-ax$.

Now if the probability density function (PDF) of $n$ for example be Gaussian $\mathcal N(\mu_n, \sigma_n)$, i.e. $n\sim \mathcal N(\mu_n, \sigma_n)$), then $(y-ax)\sim \mathcal N(\mu_n,\sigma_n)$.

Comment: $P$ looks like conditional probability... but of what event?

Comment: Consider a very simple case. Let the random variable $X$ and $N$ be defined as follows
$$\begin{matrix}X=\begin{cases}1&\text{with probability }p\\0&\text{with probability }1-p\end{cases} , \ \ N=\begin{cases}2&\text{with probability }q\\3&\text{with probability }1-q\end{cases}\end{matrix},$$
and let $a=1$. Now, as an example,

$$P(X+N=3|X=1)=P(X=1,N=\color{red}2|X=1)=P(N=\color{red}2).$$ 
Is this what you mean?

Comment: Is $x$ discrete or continuous? Same for $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ and $N$ be discrete random variables and, assuming that $P(X=x)>0,$ consider the following conditional probability:
$$P(aX+N=s|X=x).$$ 
Given the event that $X=x$, if $N$ has a value $n=s-ax$, which it takes with a positive probability, then
$$P(aX+N=s|X=x)=\frac{P(X=x,ax+N=s)}{P(X=x)}=\frac{P(X=x)P(ax+N=s)}{P(X=x)}$$
$$=P(ax+N=s)=P(N=s-ax)=P(N=n).$$
Given the event that $X=x$ if $N$ doesn't have a suitable value $n$, which it takes with positive probability then 
$$P(aX+N|X=x)=P(N=n)=0.$$

I am not sure if the above argumentation corresponds to the script below $$P(ax+n|x)=P(n).$$